# Too much JSON info

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using the following to convert data from mysql to JSON:

```
$sql = "select img_name from user_gallery_images where user_id=$_SESSION[user_id]";

        $response = array();
        $posts = array();

        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

            $file=$row['img_name']; 
            $fileDir = "gallery/$file.jpg";
            $posts[] = array('thumb'=> $fileDir, 'image'=> $fileDir);

        } 

        $response['posts'] = $posts;

        $fp = fopen('/home/public_html/users/'.$settings[username].'/gallery/gallery.json', 'w');
        $jsonData = stripslashes(json_encode($response));
        fwrite($fp, $jsonData);
        fclose($fp);
```

Which works well and creates e.g.

```
{"posts":
[
{"thumb":"gallery/tess1367386438.jpg","image":"gallery/tess1367386438.jpg"},
{"thumb":"gallery/tess1367386538.jpg","image":"gallery/tess1367386538.jpg"}
]
}
```

But, the JQuery plug in i'm using it with won't read it with the outer "posts" container

**QUESTION:**

How can I strip the outer "posts" container in the JSON to produce only:

```
[
{"thumb":"gallery/tess1367386438.jpg","image":"gallery/tess1367386438.jpg"},
{"thumb":"gallery/tess1367386538.jpg","image":"gallery/tess1367386538.jpg"}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$jsonData = json_encode($response['posts']);
```

Comment: @zerlms the OP has it in the code, so I am assuming he has it there for a reason but yes its not really needed.

Comment: @SabeenMalik Perfect, many thanks, I'm learning a little more each day!